# Ember js controllerSetup with call to async model works with breakpoint but not without

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Obligatory version info:

```
"DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.0-beta.1+canary.ffa2c83c"
"DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.d55198c2"
"DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0"
"DEBUG: jQuery     : 2.1.0"
```

I have an ember data model set up like this

```
App.User = DS.model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    sites: DS.hasMany('site', {async:true})
});
```

And a route set up like this:

```
App.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites').then(function(sites){
            controller.set('model', sites);
        });
    });
 });
```

The auth controller gives me the currently logged in user and I want the Sites route to only display sites that are relevant to the currently logged in user.

This however does not work and throws an error

```
"Error while loading route: App.SitesRoute<.setupController"
```

**What is interesting is that this setupcontroller hook actually works if I throw a break point in there, no error occurs and the data loads fine in to the UI.**

This leads me to believe that there is a problem with the promise loading going on here but I cannot workout why.  I would have thought that when the 'model.sites' promise fulfills the controllers model gets set which in turn populates the content and my ui.  But this does not seem to be the case.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit 1**

Here is a variation which has similar results.  if I put a break point on the return statement in the model hook of the route, it works. Otherwise it does not

```
App.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites');
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

**Edit 2**

Ok here is something that makes this code work. But seems to me is contrary to the [docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/)  which state this:

> "In cases where data is available asynchronously, you can just return
>   a promise from the model hook, and Ember will wait until that promise
>   is resolved before rendering the template."

I had thought that the call to self.controllerFor('auth').get('sites') was a promise if the 'sites' relationship was marked 'asyc:true' am I mistaken in this?.

So I can do this and it works, which I guess it kind of simulating the break point:

```
App.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var self = this;
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
            Ember.run.later(function() {
                    resolve(self.controllerFor('auth').get('sites'));
                  }, 3000);
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller,model) {
            controller.set('content', model);
    }
});
```

**Edit 3**

Ok, I have found something that works, which I will go with for now, but I am still unhappy with not understanding what is going on or why.  There is something that I neglected to mention which is that I am using the [ember-data-django-rest-adapter](https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter) I cant tell if this is what is causing the issue despite several hours of debugging the internals of ember and the adapter.

Without further ado here is what ended up working:

```
App.SitesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller,model) {
        this.controllerFor('auth').get('content').then(function (user) {
           user.get('sites').then(function (sites) {
               controller.set('content', sites);
           });
        });
    }
});
```

Any insights to why this works when the other approaches don't would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does RestrictedRoute look like?

Comment: I forgot to take that out.  That has no impact on what I am doing. I'll modify the original question. The issue occurs just the same with Ember.Route

Answer (score 1):

What I would do to keep all controllers aware of the current user is to inject the currentUserController into all my controllers in the ember initializer. Then, you can get the currentUser from any point in your controller by accessing it like this.get('currentUser').]

In your case, I would try this and see if it works:

```
model: function() {
  return this.controllerFor('auth').get('sites');
},

setupController: function(controller,model) {
   model.then(function(response) {
      controller.set('content', response);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good idea. But that still wont help me with my sites route whose model requires the currentUser's hasMany relationship to be fulfilled

Comment: But that should be not different to what I am already doing without the "then" method which I have already tried with this controller.set('model',this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites') );

Comment: This also exhibits the same behavior where a breakpoint on that statement gives enough time for the call to return and the data be populated on the UI. Without the breakpoint no data displays and the call never seems to happen to the REST API.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but when the line this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites') executes, what I think, *I think* happens is, it returns a promise, that promise gets resolved, it returns a list of sites when its resolved, and your .then( ) does not have any effect as the list is not a promise.

Comment: I don't use a .then() when attempting that way. I just call return this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites') with no .then()

Comment: Ah I see. Well, I didn't see your message until after I had replied. Anyway, why are you not having a model hook in your router which just returns this.controllerFor('auth').get('model.sites') and saying controller.set('model', model) ?

Comment: yeah, I'll add an update with that code. It is a similar outcome though. basically if I put a break point on the return statement in the model hook it works. Otherwise it does not.

Comment: I tried that one. I have looked at the docs again and it clearly states that in the model hook for the route it will wait for the promise to fulfill before proceeding. but it seems this is not the case for some reason here because it required me to put a breakpoint to allow enough time for it to fulfill for it to proceed

Comment: In Ember 1.5.1 the object you refer to as `model` in line 6 of your example has no `then` method?!

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when I have a model relationship that uses `async: true` I can expect that when I get that relationship the result is a promise, for example:

```
var stuff = model.get('relatedCollection');
var actualStuff;

if (typeof stuff.then === 'function') {
  stuff.then(function (collection) {
    actualStuff = collection;
  });
} else {
  actualStuff = stuff;
}
```

The above is pseudo code to illustrate that when you use `aysc: true` when you define your model reltionship that you most likely will see a promise when you `get` that related collection.

I've noticed that when the promise is resolved, maybe even when you have a breakpoint set, then when you `get` the related collection you may see the actual collection instead of the promise as a result.

So, when I do use `aysc: true` I typically use the branching code to first check if the result is thenable `typeof thing.then === 'function'` If so, I treat the assigned value as a promise; and use the thenable syntax to get the actual collection of models after the promise is resolved.